# The website from custom domain is different from the website from host domain (stylesheet not updated in custom domain)

Tags: dns, web-hosting, custom-domain

I built a personal website and hosted it on Heroku.

However, after recent update and push to Heroku, the website from the custom domain (http://www.kevinportfolio.com) is different from the website from the host domain (https://kevin-portfolio-page.herokuapp.com).[image: correct display from host domain][image: incorrect display from custom domain]

The first one is from host domain and is the correct display.

The second one is from custom domain and does not have a image and styling.

After some troubleshooting, I found out that the stylesheet.css for the custom domain is not updated as it is for the host domain. I assume it has something to do with the custom domain set up and DNS configuration. But I have no clue on how to resolve this issue.

This problem has persisted for more than 48 hours, the time suggested for the DNS to update.

Comment: Not reproducible. For me both sites look exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the check. It seems that something is wrong with the chrome browser. The firefox browser displays the image correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that something is wrong with the chrome browser. I disabled the cache and reloaded the website and it worked.

The steps I took:

1. right-click the website and Inspect
2. In develop tools, go to the Network tab.
3. under the Network tab, check the 'disable cache' checkbox.
4. reload the website.

And the stylesheet is now updated.